# The program doesn't give the expected output

Tags: c++

*"Write a program which reads **n** numbers and which determines a number **c**, the smallest of the read numbers which contains the largest digit found in them."*

*Example: n=10 ; numbers: 23 12 64 12 72 345 67 23 71 634 ; c=67 (the largest digit found in these numbers is 7 and it can be found in 72, 67, 71. The smallest number is 67)*

I don't know why, but my program doesn't work. Every time, it shows me that c=0.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, prec, crt, digitMax, t, a, i, c;
    digitMax=0;
    t=0;

    cout<<"Give the number of numbers: "; cin>>n;
    cout<<"Give the first number: "; cin>>prec;
    do{
        a=prec%10;
        prec=(prec-a)/10;
        if(a>digitMax){
            digitMax=a;
        }
    } while(prec!=0);


    for(i=1; i<n; i++){
        cout<<"Give the next number: "; cin>>crt;
        do{
            a=crt%10;
            crt=(crt-a)/10;
            if(a>t){
                t=a;
            }
        } while(crt!=0);

        if(digitMax>t){
            c=prec;
        } else if(digitMax<t) {
            digitMax=t;
            c=crt;
        } else if(prec>=crt){
            c=crt;
        } else{
            c=prec;
        }
        prec=crt;
    }
    cout<<"c is "<<c;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: Have you tried to split the program logic into separate functions and check if each function is doing what you think it does?

Comment: *Every time, it shows me that c=0.* Because  your `do-while` loops end when `prec=0` and `crt=0` respectively. And ultimately you are assigning either `prec` or `crt` to `c`.

Comment: @AditiRawat Thank you! I created another two variables, **x** and **y**, and I assigned **x** the value of _prec_ and **y** the value of _crt_. However, if I input the example, it shows me that `c=71` instead of 67.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay, I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are doing everything inside a single function make it very complex. The proper way to tackle problem is first define a small functions whcih are doing smaller tasks.

One which calculates biggest digit in number:

```
int BigestDigitOf(int x)
{
    x = std::abs(x);
    int biggestDigit = 0;
    while (x)
    {
        biggestDigit = std::max(biggestDigit, x%10);
        x/=10;
    }
    return biggestDigit;
}
```

And one which compares two numbers according to `c` definition:

```
bool BiggerDigitOrSmallerValue(int a, int b)
{
    auto bdA = BigestDigitOf(a);
    auto bdB = BigestDigitOf(b);
    if (bdA > bdB) {
        return true;
    }
    return bdA == bdB && a < b;
}
```

After that solving your problem is very simple (one line if STL is used).